# Dropdown element in jasper report

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a requirement where I need to add dropdown element to my report when exported to excel format.Dropdown has 2 values Yes or No. Once the report is generated user can view the dropdown and select yes or No from the dropdown list. Is there a way to add a dropdown element in jasper reports or iReport?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you talking about JR exporter's settings for Excel format?

Comment: I wanted to know if there is any element like combo box that ireport provides similar to frames,images elements that iReport provides currently.Or if there is a workaround to create such element in jasper reports?

Comment: The *iReport* is a report's template designer. You define how the report looks like with help of *iReport*. JasperReports has many exporters (for Excel, PDF, HTML, etc.). Do you want to have dropdown in resulting report (for example, in PDF document)?

Comment: Yes, i would want to have the drop down when the report is generated in Excel format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying the report on an HTML page, say through a JSP, then yes, definitely you could add a drop-down. Much depends though on how you are rendering the report.

Comment: Thanx for the response.The report will be generated Excel format.

Comment: Does Excel support drop-down boxes? I'm certain the answer to your question is no.